# Xcode Beta 2 - How can I see the values on swift strings in the debugging window

Tags: swift, xcode6

is there a way, to view the value of a Swift String in Xcode Beta 2.

Thank you

---

After reading the first answers, both methods doesn't seem to work reliable:

[image: couldn't see the evernoteContent String parameter]

the parameter to the function, evernoteContent will not be resolved. When I use the lldb po command, I've got a EXC_BAD_ACCESS or maybe the whole Xcode Beta 2 is crashing.

But there is a string value in evernoteContent.

Comment: I suggest examine the call stacks on crashing thread. Or try to set break points at earlier call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint in your code you can print any variable with the `po` command like this:

```
(lldb) po myString
"hello"
```

Comment: I see only gibberish like "class name = __NSAtom" and " {
  core = {
    _baseAddress = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x0000000000000000
    _countAndFlags = 0
    _owner = None
  }
}". What gives?

Comment: can't we print the description as we do in the Xcode 5 & Objective C?

Answer (score 2):

One way is what Paul Robinson pointed out. Also I normally do the following, set a break point, and examine variables in **Variables View**. Use Quick Look and Print Description buttons at bottom left.

[image]

Comment: I will look after this. This is what I normally do but I didn't see (always) the value.